# tela de login em java e banco de dados Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, login

estou estando validar o login da um sistema simples porem esta dando um erro nao realiza o login
vou mandar o código da classe e do momento em que eu tento logar.

classe LojaBD que faz a validação do usuário
[image: classe LojaBD que faz a validação do usuário]

classe que faz o teste do login
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

erro que esta gerando.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

erro atualizado[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Favor não postar código como imagem e fazer o [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro já diz tudo. Você não pode fazer executar um `SELECT` em um `executeUpdate`. Use um `executeQuery`neste caso. Altere seu código para:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM userloja WHERE email = ? AND senha = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conectarMysql().prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, loja.getEmail());
ps.setString(2, loja.getSenha());
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
return rs.isBeforeFirst();
```

> [`executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery())
>
> Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns the ResultSet object generated by the query.

Em tradução livre:

> Executa a query SQL no objeto PreparedStatement e retorna um objeto ResultSet gerado por essa query.

Comment: da uma olhada na resposta que eu dei na minha própria pergunta

Comment: ainda esta dando erro no return

Comment: ele nao identifica o return resultSet.isBeforeFirst(); fica a lapada pedindo para criar um classe resultSet

Comment: eu ja fiz isso e nao funcionou, mesmo erro

Comment: tem alguma forma de entrar em contato com voce? facebook, wpp, skype sla

Comment: sera pq é um método bool?

Comment: meu camarada eu ja coloquei o ; nunca esqueço de colocar

Comment: coloquei o o print da pergunta

Comment: vlw isso eu não sabia, obg pela ajuda e desculpa pelo trabalho que dei

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você não está usando JDBC corretamente. Vocé deveria usar `executeQuery` ao invés de `executeUpdate` para realizar SELECTs.

```
ResultSet rs = alterar.executeQuery(query);
```

[Aqui](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-select-records.htm) está um exemplo mais detalhado de como deveria ser feito.